# Setting off showcmd in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to configure vim to my needs and I find the output bar at the bottom-left pretty unnecessary and annoying and definetly slowing down my efficiency. I would just like to completly remove it throught my configuration file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The question appears to be off-topic and I am reconsidering the decission of removing it because many people can find useful as I did but if needed I will delete it immidieatly.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: oh ok sorry but I thought since it has to do with neovim which is a editor used for programming it was related to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this command:

```
:set noshowcmd
```

If you allways want this option, you can add to your .vimrc file.